# @Transaction and repository testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I've seen that `@Transactional` is better placed at the service layer but the problem is that I'm not able to test my repositories correctly because the changes are not commited.

When testing the repository `save()` method, I want to use `find()` to see if the entity was correctly saved but because `save()` changes are not commited to the database, `find()` returns null.

The only solutions I see is to add the `@Transactional` annotation:

- on the repository `save()` method
- on the `testSave()` method => but IMO this is wrong because it modifies the behavior

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, I started to learn Java two days ago.

Comment: "because the changes are not commited" didn't understand

Comment: the changes are not commited to the database

Comment: I still didn't get you. To test the functionality, you can write a Junit test case [@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)], and mark at @Transactional [by default rollback true].

Comment: @user3168219 do you wish to roll back the changes still at the end of the test? or do you use memory-based db that gets cleaned at the end? or how you plan to remove the entries committed? note also that this is integration testing, not unit testing. You're better off separating the two.

Comment: I use a different configuration for production and test and indeed I use the H2 database for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the changes committed to the database you only need the queries issued in the same transaction. Next you shouldn't be using the same means by which you store the data to retrieve the data. Basically you should use plain jdbc to test if it was added.

```
public class TestClass extends AbstractTransactionalSpringJUnit4ContextTests {

    private TestRepository repo; 

 @Test
 public void testSave() {
    int rowCount = countRowsInTable("your-table-name");
    repo.save(yourEntity);
    repo.flush(); 
    int rowCountAfter = countRowsInTable("your-table-name");
    assertTrue(rowCountAfter - rowCount == 1); // Or whatever you like to verify the row was added 
 }
```

Note: If you don't extend `JpaRepository` there is no `flush` method, instead you can inject the `EntityManager` in the testcase and call `flush` on there.

Instead of only testing the row count you could also use the `jdbcTemplate` from the `AbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTests` to retrieve the newly added row and compare with what you expected it to be.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I use `JpaRepository` `save()` not `saveAndFlush()`, so I will need to call `flush` manually in the test.

Answer (score -4):

That's why you would start testing by writing unit tests while writing production code. But as you started learning Java just two days ago you really should not get into transaction management right off the bat. Learn the basics and the design first.

Comment: how is this an answer to the question?